# eMac with no OS

Tags: macos, software

I have an eMac with no OS and I have no install disk. Can someone provide instructions on creating an install USB or DVD for the latest version of OS X which is compatible with my eMac?

Answer (score 3):

According to everyman.com, [here](https://everymac.com/systems/apple/emac/index-emac.html) is a list of all eMacs. OS X 10.4 (Tiger) and/or OS X 10.5 (Leopard) should be compatible with your eMac. You could try buying an used DVD or burn a DVD from am ISO download. For example, there is [this ISO download](https://archive.org/details/OsxLeopardInstall) of Leopard (which I have not verified). If successful, the you should install the [Mac OS X 10.5.8 Combo Update](https://support.apple.com/kb/DL866?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US).

If Leopard will not install, then try Tiger. For example, there is [this ISO download](https://archive.org/details/macosx10.4tigerretaildvd) of Tiger (which I have not verified). If successful, the you should install the [Mac OS X 10.4.11 Combo Update (PPC)](https://support.apple.com/kb/dl170?locale=en_US).

Comment: Though this answers the question accurately it’s worth noting that these older versions of Mac OS X aren’t considered secure, so if the machine is to be connected to the Internet, installing some lightweight Linux distro instead would be safer.